# Stanford CoreNLP - relation annotator

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to use the Stanford CoreNLP relation extractor (http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/relationExtractor.shtml).

I've installed the CoreNLP, like it suggested and I tried adding the relation parameter to the annotator pipeline but to no avail. Below is the code that I tried entering through my command line in Linux.

```
java -cp "*" -Xxm1g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse,relation -file <path toinput file>
```

The error message is that when it's trying to add the annotator relation, it states:

```
Unable to resolve "edu/stanford/nlp/models/supervised_relation_extractor/roth_relation_model_pipelineNER.ser" as either a class path, filename or URL.
```

I tried searching the web to see if I could just download the roth_relation_model_pipelineNER.ser file and just stick it in the models directory but I can't find it (I also don't know Java very well).

Please let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks.

In response to @StanfordNLPHelp 's (thank you for your quick reply BTW):

I am running the command with the models.jar file in the same directory and it is picking it up (screenshot below):

[image]

In addition, I downloaded the newest version of the CoreNLP zip file from the website. Unzipped it and also unpacked the models.jar file (stanford-parser-3.5.2-models.jar). I went to the models directory but there was only the lexparser and parser directories there, I didn't see one for supervised_relation_extractor. Attached is a screenshot. 
[image]

Also, this is a side note but I had a similar problem with the pos annotator as well. I was running into the same issue where it couldn't find the file. But I was able to download a separate .jar file and place it where the program wanted it using this website (question #6 - http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/pos-tagger-faq.shtml) and that was able to work.

Comment: Essentially, I just want to be able to run a the relationship extractor in Stanford's CoreNLP software in a Linux terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That file is in this jar: stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models.jar

When you run your command in the Terminal, that .jar file needs to be in the directory you are running the command in for the -cp "*" to pick it up.  If you see that error it means that you don't have stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models.jar in your classpath.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I am running the command from that directory with models.jar file. Since I can't attach pictures in these replies, I've extended my question to elaborate. I'm still looking at other alternatives. Thank you again!

Comment: Oh wait, I'm dumb. you said stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models.jar... Let me check this out.

Comment: You want to download the full toolkit from this link, not just the parser: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml

Comment: Ah ok, you're correct, thank you so much! you saved me!